# MySQL Query on Only Recent Items for Big Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

We have a "Thanks" system implemented across our forum. We also have a "See Your Recent Thanks" page, which is now becoming much slower as the "Thanks" table grows well into the millions.

Here is the structure of the "Thanks" table:

```
Field    Type        Null   Key Default Extra 
id       int(10)     NO     PRI NULL    auto_increment 
userid   int(10)     NO     MUL NULL 
username varchar(50) NO         NULL 
date     int(10)     NO         NULL 
postid   int(10)     NO     MUL NULL
```

On the "Recent Thanks" page, the following query is run for the current user ($uid):

```
  SELECT post_thanks.postid, post_thanks.date, post_thanks.username, post_thanks.userid, thread.title 
    FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post_thanks AS post_thanks
         LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post AS post
                ON post_thanks.postid = post.postid
         LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "thread AS thread
                ON thread.threadid = post.threadid      
   WHERE post.userid = '$uid'
   ORDER BY post_thanks.id DESC
   LIMIT 20
```

This results in the 20 most recent post thanks for that user. Now that the post_thanks table is over a million lines long, this query takes over one second to complete. Sometimes it comes from cache faster, but I am trying to consistently optimize it, since users typically only view their "Thanks" when they have a new notification (ie, cache will have changed).

My first problem is that this query uses Filesort instead of Index. Given the table structure, shouldn't ORDER BY post_thanks.id use Index?

My second problem is that I don't need to query 5 million lines just to get the most recent thanks. There are typically 5,000 thanks per week across the forum. If a user doesn't check the forum for a week, it's okay that their recent thanks may have disappeared. So I modified the query like this (only line changed is #2)

```
  SELECT post_thanks.postid, post_thanks.date, post_thanks.username, post_thanks.userid, thread.title 
  FROM (SELECT * FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post_thanks ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5000) AS post_thanks
  LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post AS post
  ON post_thanks.postid = post.postid
  LEFT JOIN " . TABLE_PREFIX . "thread AS thread
  ON thread.threadid = post.threadid    
  WHERE post.userid = '$uid' 
  ORDER BY post_thanks.id DESC
  LIMIT 20
```

This query runs consistently at less than .001 seconds, even with cache disabled.

Is this a good way to deal with our performance problems? Or is there a better way to speed up this query without ignoring older data? I'm still confused as to why Index is not being used either way.

Comment: Whats you schema look like?  You  have keys and indexes created properly?

Comment: What does he query plan look like? Have you looked at using EXPLAIN  (see reference here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html )

Comment: By the way, your 5000 limit applies to the most recent 5000 posts .. not the most recent history for a particular user.

Comment: @Dan, I ran 'describe post_thanks'. Is there something else I should run to share the schema with you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the query using `inner join` rather than `left join`:

```
SELECT post_thanks.postid, post_thanks.date, post_thanks.username, post_thanks.userid, thread.title 
FROM " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post_thanks post_thanks INNER JOIN
     " . TABLE_PREFIX . "post AS post
     ON post_thanks.postid = post.postid INNER JOIN
     " . TABLE_PREFIX . "thread AS thread
     ON thread.threadid = post.threadid      
WHERE post.userid = '$uid'
ORDER BY post_thanks.id DESC
LIMIT 20;
```

Next, I notice that the `where` condition is `post.userid = '$uid'`.  Could this really or also be:  post_thanks.userid = '$uid'?

I would suggest using inner joins, with `where post_thanks.userid = '$uid'` and with the index:  `post_thanks(userid, id)`.

Comment: post_thanks.userid is the userid of the person who gave the thanks, whereas post.userid is the userid of the person receiving the thanks. 

I will try inner joins. How can I specify the index, like you suggested? I thought MySQL automatically decided which index to use?

Comment: @PFBilling . . . Perhaps you can change the `thanks` table to have both user ids in it.  That small change would make the query much easier to optimize.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. I guess I'm just confused as to why Limiting 3000 saves so much time. Shouldn't the original query just Sort and grab the first 20 where userid = $uid, and then stop sorting? Given the time differences, it seems like it's sorting all 5 million rows and then just grabbing the first 20.

Comment: @PFBilling . . . All the data matching the conditions is sorted.  And *then* the first 20 results are returned.  I doubt it is sorting 5 million rows.  It is probably getting every thanks (because of the `left join`), filtering those by the user, sorting the results, and then choosing the first 20.  You can put `explain` before the query to get an idea of what it is doing.

Comment: Your solution in the second comment got this lightning fast. Just added a new column to the post_thanks table for received_userid, ran a quick data update for existing entries, and now no more massive join are needed with the post table. Thanks!!